# loadbalancing in Ubuntu servers with MapServer

Tags: load-balancing, ubuntu-10.04, mapserver

I have 3 Ubuntu 10.04 machines with MapServer installed and configured. I need to get load balancing among those 3 machines. I find that there are some third-party applications with different features. I am wondering if anyone has specific preference or come across to any documentation that could be good starting point for getting started to load-balancing in MapServer.

Thank you in advance!

Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, you may use mod_proxy to do it. Other web servers like nginx or lighttpd have a similar feature.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Apache and will certainly take a look on mod_proxy. I hope it works well with MapServer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already solved this, perhaps give this a go...

http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/1999-August/053932.html